# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape porque una variable se modifica "sola"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy un código y en función de qué valores le dé a una de las variables, me funciona bien o me da el siguiente error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
>   shape

He estado repasándolo todo. He localizado el punto en el que me da el error y creo que el por qué. Lo cual me lleva a algo un tanto extraño.

La linea donde me da el error es en la segunda de estas dos:

```
leng_half_mask = np.int(leng_mask / 2)

vern = tls.vernier(mask, mask_star, leng_half_mask, leng_m_star_small)
```

`mask`y `mask_star`son listas y `leng_half_mask` y `leng_m_star_small` son escalares.
Cuando ejecuto todo el programa hasta la primera línea (`leng_half_mask`), el tamaño de `mask` es `370` y el de `mask_star` es `368`.
Cuando ejecuto la siguiente línea (`vern`) estos valores se modifican y pasan a tener un tamaño de `372` cada uno. 
Creo que al ejecutar la línea `vern` y entrar en la función, el hecho de que `mask`y `mask_star` tengan tamaños diferentes genera algún conflicto.
Pero ¿por qué se modifica el tamaño de `mask` y `mask_star`?

La función `tls.vernier` a la que llamo tiene la siguiente definición. Para que esta función haga lo que debe, es necesario que `A`y `B` sean del mismo tamaño. Si son de diferente tamaño, entonces añade ceros a la lista más corta hasta que ambaas listas sean de igual tamaño.:

```
def vernier(A, B, cA, cB):

    long_A = len(A)
    long_B = len(B)

    dist_0cA = cA + 1
    dist_0cB = cB + 1

    dist_cAend = long_A - cA
    dist_cBend = long_B - cB

    dif_0 = dist_0cA - dist_0cB
    dif_end = dist_cAend - dist_cBend

    d0_abs = np.abs(dif_0)

    if dif_0 < 0:
        for i in range(0, d0_abs):
            A.insert(0, 0)
    elif dif_0 > 0:
        for j in range(0, d0_abs):
            B.insert(0, 0)

    de_abs = np.abs(dif_end)

    if dif_end < 0:
        for k in range(0, de_abs):
            A.append(0)
    elif dif_end > 0:
        for l in range(0, de_abs):
            B.append(0)

    long = len(A)
    vernier = []
    for m in range(0, long):
        if A[m] == 1 or B[m] == 1:
            vernier.append(1)
        else:
            vernier.append(0)

    return vernier
```

Comment: He hecho más pruebas y definitivamente, la llamada a la función `tls.vernier` modifica los parametros que se le pasan como A y B que en mi casocorresponden a `mask` y `mask_star`.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)